# on TabGesture Swift UI

Tags: arrays, swift, scrollview, swiftui

look for some help on my study of the scrollView in swiftUI.
I have a scroll view that display the value of an array, base when the user tap on the different item of scroll view I want to display it on the textField below.

how can I pass the array value to the text field??

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let post = ["TEST1 ","Test 2" , "Test 3","TEST4 ","Test 5" , "Test 6"]
    var temp = ""
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
                        HStack(spacing: 100) {
                            ForEach(post, id: \.self){ item in


                                ZStack {
                                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 190, height: 170, alignment: .center)
                                    Text(item)
                                }.onTapGesture {
                                    // pass the value off Scroll View to the text
                                    debugPrint("\(item)")

                                }

                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, 10)
                    })
                .frame(height: 190)
            Spacer()
            Text("dispaly here array value selected")
            Spacer()
        }

    }
}
```

thank for helping me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is you need to `@State temp` when you need to assign to a @State value inside the view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
let post = ["TEST1 ","Test 2" , "Test 3","TEST4 ","Test 5" , "Test 6"]

@State private var temp = ""


var body: some View {

    VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, content: {
                    HStack(spacing: 100) {
                        ForEach(post, id: \.self){ item in


                            ZStack {
                                Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 190, height: 170, alignment: .center)
                                Text(item)
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                // pass the value off Scroll View to the text
                                self.temp = item

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                })
            .frame(height: 190)
        Spacer()
        Text( self.temp)
        Spacer()
       }

      }
   }
```